# Swap - One disk or multiple disks

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, swap, swap-file

Hi there internet hivemind!

I have a EC2(t2-large) on AWS running Ubuntu. Due to high memory consumption I'm going to add about 8G of Swap.

The machine has 4 disks, all of them with enough space.
What is better? 2G in each disk or 8G in a single one?

Thanks!

Comment: For physical disks it'd make sense to spread it out, not sure which would work better in an virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

All of the storage on T-instances is EBS-backed, so it isn't going to be very fast -- and for swap, you want fast.   You might consider moving to an M5-instance, where the EBS-backed storage is speed rated (see [instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)).  The price is $0.0032 higher per hour and you lose burstable CPU, so YMMV.

Otherwise, consider mounting a separate, EBS-optimized volume for your swapfile.  See this for speed considerations (see [speed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html))

If you move to Ubuntu 18.04, the swap is no longer a partition but rather a file, which may make testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

EBS gp2 general purpose SSD gives you 3 IOPS / GB, but that burstable, as per [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) and the diagram below. If you provision four 2GB disks each will have 6 IOPS. If you provision one 8GB disk you get 24 IOPS.

So if your workload is split evenly across the disks then small disks will be as good as large disks. If the workload is random then one larger volume will likely give you better performance. Given it's swap you don't know how it will work, so I'd go with the one 8GB volume.

Using EBS as swap works, I do it myself with my t2.nano. Of course performance will be relatively poor, worse than a local disk. You might also consider optimization to reduce RAM usage.

[image: AWS GP2 burstable]